# How to inherit a page class from a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, code-behind

Ayup

I might be asking a dumb question, but I have a client for whom I need to build many websites (10+) (asp.net 3.5) which will all the pages on each site will have the same codebehind, but the sites will launching in different regions and whilst following the same template, will have different content.

I have built and launched site 1, and sites 2, 3 & 4 is nearly live, but it occurs to me that as all the sites are basically the same, the code is going to get more complicated to update as it will be duplicated, so if I need to do a bug fix on one site, I'll need to do the fix on all websites (and this is going to get complicated.)

I was wondering if it possible to somehow create a class library of all the current aspx.cs files, reference this dll in each website and then inherit these classes into the .aspx.cs files. So default.aspx in each site would still have a CodeFile of "Default.aspx.cs", but Default.aspx.cs would inherit the corresponing class from the dll:

```
using WebPagesClass;
public partial class _Default : WebPagesClass._Default
{ }
```

The reason for doing it like this is that if I need to change any code on a specific website (for minor changes in languages for instance), I can override the page functions and change the parts required. For all other pages which have not cha, I can just copy from a single website.

Is this vaguely possible? If not anyone one got any killer suggestions of how to manage so many websites from a single codebase?

Cheers
T

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this. But you will need to ensure that your base class inherits from System.Web.Page.

So create a library, add the necessary references (System.Web, etc.) and create your base class:

```
public class MyBasePage: System.Web.Page
{

}
```

Then you can specify that as your base class for all your other pages.

As for using this single class as the direct code-behind class for all your aspx pages, this may get tricky because the pages will likely have their own individual asp.net controls on them, and therefore the code-behind classes for each page will indeed be slightly different.

I assume you are wanting to do this work because there is a bunch of similar code in the pages, but I imagine there is also some specific code/control declarations as well. So I would create the base class and put the common code in there, and just inherit from that class...

Comment: Thanks for the responce, to clarify I was planning on something like the following with a different class for each page type (not one code base for every page), all the pages will be different (say 20 pages on each site) but all sites will have the 20 different pages: namespace WebPagesClass { public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {}}

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to move all differences between the sites into ASP.Net Themes or config files? Sounds like a better approach to me